# Pandas: cumsum in the past and in the future

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

Given a single value, fixed in time:

```
2010-06-01 : 100
```

And a list of changes that have happened to that value, both in the past and in the future (relative to the fixed date):

```
Date         Diff
2010-04-01   30
2010-05-01   20
2010-07-01   60
2010-08-01   10
```

I want the following result:

```
Date         Value
2010-04-01   50
2010-05-01   80
2010-06-01   100
2010-07-01   160
2010-08-01   170
```

Basically, diffs after the fixed date are to be cumulatively summed, and diffs before the fixed date are to be cumulatively subtracted.

My current solution is:

1. Filter the diff DataFrame into two: one contains past, and one contains future values.
2. Negate the past DF, append it to the current DF, sort descending, and do a cumsum.
3. Take the future DF, append it to the current DF, sort ascending, and do a cumsum.
4. Append everything together.

---

*Some starter code:*

```
pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2010-04-01', '2010-05-01', '2010-07-01', '2010-08-01'], 'Diff': [30,20,60,10]})

pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2010-06-01'], 'Value': [100]})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create conditions and apply function by them:

```
#convert to datetimes
df1.Date = pd.to_datetime(df1.Date)
df2.Date = pd.to_datetime(df2.Date)
#join together
df = (pd.concat([df1, df2.rename(columns={'Value':'Diff'})])
       .sort_values('Date')
       .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
        Date  Diff
0 2010-04-01    30
1 2010-05-01    20
2 2010-06-01   100
3 2010-07-01    60
4 2010-08-01    10

m1 = df.Date < df2.loc[0, 'Date']
m2 = ~m1
#condition for select only appended value
m3 = m2[[m2.idxmax()]]
print (m3)
2    True
Name: Date, dtype: bool
```

---

```
#multiple by -1 by condition m1
df.loc[m1, 'Diff'] *= -1
#chained m1 and m3 for inverse cumulative sum
df.loc[m1 | m3, 'Diff'] = df.loc[m1 | m3, 'Diff'].iloc[::-1].cumsum()
#classic cumsum
df.loc[m2, 'Diff'] = df.loc[m2, 'Diff'].cumsum()
print (df)

        Date  Diff
0 2010-04-01    50
1 2010-05-01    80
2 2010-06-01   100
3 2010-07-01   160
4 2010-08-01   170
```